# Maximum number of Send Attempts

Tags: c#, .net, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I am using PushSharp v2.0.4.  I have a push notification service (i.e., Windows Service) that sends out notifications every minute.  The load on the service is quite small.  At most, I will send four notification per run.

When my service starts, it runs fine for about 2hrs before I start seeing the following message:

```
2013-06-04 07:59:01.0857|Error|Failure: PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService -> 
The maximum number of Send attempts to send the notification was reached! -> {"aps":{"badge":2}}
```

Once this message appears, it seems like PushSharp is not able to get past it very easily.  I continue to see this message until I restart my service.

I should mention that while this error is occurring, I do see some random Sent messages go through.  For example:

```
2013-06-04 07:54:04.3982|Info|Sent: PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService -> {"aps":{"badge":2}}
```

I am running PushSharp with its default configuration.

Any thoughts on what's causing the failures?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? It seems i have the same problem after 4-5 Pns are sent i get the same failure . Pls share if u have any solution.

Comment: This is usually a certificate issue.  Can you post a full stack trace of the error from the error log?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue. The issue ended up being that when exporting the p12 we multi selected to export public and private to generate the p12. When only exporting the public, the size of the p12 was 3217 bytes. The 3217 byte file worked. If your p12 is 6140 bytes you'll need to regenerate it.